# Charge transfer in two different metals by touching them

Tags: electrostatics, charge, conductors

When we touch two metallic conductors one is neutral and other has excess of charges,

Case 1-
Both metals are of copper, then we can calculate actual charges on them at steady state by capacitance formula.

Case 2-
One metal is of copper and other of aluminium, and again we can calculate steady state charges by capacitance formula.

Problem -
If size and shape of conductors remain the same then calculated charge on both cases will also be the same because capacitance depends on size and shape but intuitively why can this be true? Even changing metals doesn't change anything about charge transfer which seems quite counterintuitive to me or am I missing something?
And does time constants (charging time) in both cases will change or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several factors which could in principle affect what happens when objects made of two different metals touch, but in practice their effects are not significant. Resistivity is one, but equilibrium will be reached too quickly for its effect to be easily observed. If there is both some corrosion of the metals and a thin layer of moisture between the metals there could be a battery effect, but this would often be shorted out, and in any case is very small compared with the electrostatic charge.

Treating the different metals merely as conductors works well in most situations.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any mathematical formula to exactly determine transient charge at any time or to see how different metals exactly behave at transient charge transfer?

Comment: For a very rough estimate - Capacitance of a spherical conductor is $4\pi\epsilon_0 r$,  $0.1m$ radius gives $C\approx10^{-11}$. Estimate resistance for 1mm thick aluminium sphere from halfway around as $R=\rho\frac{l}{A}$, using an average cross section area. This will be $\approx 2.6\times10^{-8}\times\frac{\pi}{2}\times0.1\div((2\pi\times 0.1\times0.001+0)/2)=1.3\times10^{-5}$. Time constant $ =RC \approx 10^{-11}\times10^{-5}=10^{-16}$ sec, a very short time. Copper has a lower resistance, so a shorter time, but still of the same order of magnitude.